# Intellij Hibernate Entity generation configuration

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea

Is there a way to customize the Hibernate Entity generation with JPA annotations, in IntelliJ IDEA. By default the  POJOs have method accessType (in getters), adds schema information in table annotation and all the annotations are not imported, but expanded in place. Also the method and parameter ordering of slightly off (property declaration, getters and setters).

Note: I am using IntelliJ Version 11.

Answer (score 3):

Before generation you must add the default orm.xml near persistence.xml, please see below link:

[IDEA-64709 JPA: Generate field access](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64709)